# ELI5: Why can you call class methods within class methods without explicitly stating the class itself? (Ruby/Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, class-method

Sorry, the title is kind of confusing but I just discovered something that's quite mindboggling. When you call class methods inside class methods, you don't have to put a `self` before it in order for it to execute. I don't understand why this works.

For instance, suppose you have a model `Food` class with the following schema:

```
  create_table "foods", force: :cascade do |t|    
    t.string  "name", null: false
    t.string  "food_type", null: false
    t.datetime "expiration_date", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

class Food < ApplicationRecord
  def self.output_new
    new(name: 'marshmallow', food_type: 'snack')
  end
end
```

Instead of writing `Food.new` or `self.new`, simply writing `new` returns a newly created instance. Writing the methods using the Eigenclass syntax also yields the same results. This isn't limited to `new` but it works with practically all applicable class methods like `create, delete, instance_methods`, etc.

I've searched why this is the case, but I don't really understand. Would someone please explain why this is happening to ensure I'm not hallucinating?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call a method, Ruby first checks to see if it's defined on `self`. There is only one exception to this that I know of - if you have a local variable with the same name as the method, it will reference the local variable instead:

```
def num; 1; end
num = 2
num # => 2
```

Class methods are the same as instance methods in this regard.

It's easier to think of the cases where you *can't* omit the self:

- When using a setter method e.g. `self.foo = "bar"` it's required because Ruby needs to know you're not trying to just set a local variable (as `foo = "bar"` would):

  ```
  class Test
    attr_writer :foo
    def initialize
      self.foo = 1 # calls the setter method
      foo = 2 # creates a local variable
    end
  end
  ```
- When there's ambiguity between a local variable and a method (both have the same name) and you want to call the method:

  ```
  class Foo
    def self.a; 1; end
    def self.b
      a = 2
      a # references local variable
      self.a # calls method
      a() # can also call the method by writing out parens (removes ambiguity)
    end
  end
  ```
- When `self` is not what you want it to be in that scope.

  ```
  class Foo
    def self; a; 1
  end

  a # obviously doesn't work, it isn't defined here
  Foo.a # works
  ```
- When the method name is the same as a reserved word (e.g. `class`)

  ```
  def class_name
    class.name # syntax error, it thinks you want to define a class
    self.class.name # works 
  end
  ```